# How to get substring after pattern match? And remove found subString from Initial String

Tags: java, regex, substring

I have this string

```
String s1 = "FETCH /Students/Mark/School";
```

and I have this pattern:

```
String pattern = "FETCH /Students/.+?/School";
```

and after it matches, I need to get `"Mark"` out of that string. Is it possible?

SOLVED: getSubString, use this pattern  "FETCH /Students/(.+?)/School";

Comment: `String pattern = "FECTH /Students/(.+?)/School";` and use captured group #1

Comment: `"FETCH /Students/(.+?)/School"` and `matcher.group(1)` - you also have a typo in `FETCH`.

Comment: @NoobCoder, please post the result you are seeking.

Comment: Cool, thanx man! and would it be possible to remove the group(1),  to end up with :  FECTH /Students/School  , so that i can use the hashCode(), to find a value in a map. Again THANK YOU!!!

Comment: @stribizhev seems you were right :)

Comment: I am now busy with kids, feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @NoobCoder please edit your question to specify exactly what you want. If you remove `"Mark"` you're left with `FETCH /Students//School` (note `//` in the middle)

Comment: i want to end up with FETCH /Students/School

Comment: @NoobCoder right, but edit the question rather than commenting - comments are supposed to be transient - the question should stand on its own and be clear in itself

Comment: It is ok, i can work with the // thing, so new post? or an answer?

Comment: Just edit this one, someone will answer it for you!

Comment: @NoobCoder: So, are you looking for [this?](http://ideone.com/yMeJXs) Or [even this](http://ideone.com/qLyFaJ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simple `replaceAll` to obtain what you want:

```
String s1 = "FETCH /Students/Mark/School";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("FETCH /Students/[^/]+/School", "FETCH /Students/School");
System.out.println(s1);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/718k4e)

The `[^/]+` subpattern matches 1 or more characters other than a `/`. Since the parts you want to keep are known, you do not need to use capturing groups, just use a literal in the replacement string.

And here is a substring way of getting the result you seek (for completeness, based on the assumption that `FETCH /Students/` is a known beginning of the string, and then follows some substring consisting of characters other than `/` up to then `/` plus the rest of string you need to keep):

```
String s1 = "FETCH /Students/Mark/School";
String endPart = s1.substring(s1.indexOf("/", 17));
System.out.println(s1.substring(0, 15) + endPart);
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/25BLi8)